# How to block website on Network adapter level in Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows-10, internet, network-adapter

I have 2 network adapter, I want to block some websites ex: facebook on adapter 1(LAN ethernet), and allow to access the those same websites on adapter 2(mobile usb tathering internet)

Is there any specific software available to split and manage the website on network adapter level?

Comment: Are the two adapters connected to the same router?

Comment: @harrymc no. Its connected different router, But i don't wants to filter in the router. I wants to do it on the same pc

Comment: It would be much easier on the router, and very hard otherwise.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for your opinion. I know that it is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really blocking but you can use the route command to make Windows prefer a certain network interface when attempting to access a specific IP address or range.

To do that open an elevated cmd and type:

`route print`

This will print a long list all current routes as well as the interface list, which should be at the very top, so scroll up until you find it. Find the desired interface on the list and note the interface number.

Type the following command -

`ipconfig`

Check the default gateway of the desired interface, because you will need it later.

Also, look up the IP address of the target website -

`nslookup <website DNS name>`

If there are multiple IP addresses you will need to repeat the next step for each one.

Finally, add a static route that forces all traffic to the website's IP address through the desired interface

`route [-p] add <website IP address> mask 255.255.255.255 <interface default gateway> if <interface number>`

If you add the `-p` option the change will persist across reboots. The default behavior is that restarting your computer removes static routes.

Please note that this is done on an IP level. I don't think there is a way of using two interfaces for two websites that happen to be hosted on the same server.